# Qual è il significato di "ruspante e grifagna" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Il primo di noi che osò parlare alla cartolaia «francese» (con scarso esito, suppongo) fu il ripetente Biagi. Aveva un anno, un anno e mezzo più di noi, era tarchiato e peloso, con grossi polsi sempre vanamente inseguiti dalle maniche. Era negato a tutte le materie, interrogato rispondeva spropositi comicissimi con il suo vocione roco. Ma esercitava su noi il forte fascino di un'esperienza non solo maggiore, ma anche più **ruspante e grifagna**; fantasticavamo che avesse già avuto veri contatti con la donna, che sapesse tutto dei casini, dei preservativi e perfino dei segreti del *Kamasutra*.

La mia domanda è sugli aggettivi "ruspante" e "grifagno" in questo contesto. Ho cercato il [significato di "ruspante" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ruspante/)  e anche il [significato di "grifagno"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/grifagno/). Ho letto tutte le accezioni, ma non riesco a capire il senso di questi vocaboli nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: I would understand ruspante as 'rustic' or wild, grifagno as 'aggressive', 'dangerous', or such. In my opinion Gassman wants to give some emphasis on the 'rudeness' of such (imaginary) situation.

Comment: *Ruspante* è la gallina che vive all'aperto e *ruspa* in cerca di cibo. Quindi ruspante può significare “di modi semplici, magari un po' grezzi”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il ripetente Biagi non solo è più grande dei suoi compagni di classe, ma ha un aspetto e un comportamento non usuali per dei ragazzini "beneducati" e che ancora non hanno avuto esperienze. Essere *ruspanti* significa essere non raffinati, un po' grezzi, come riportato nel vocabolario Treccani. L'aggettivo *grifagno*, invece, che è più usato per descrivere i tratti del viso, significa *rapace*, quindi, di nuovo, non molto raffinato nei modi. Questi ragazzini immaginavano che Biagi non solo avesse già esperienze con le donne, ma anche che tali esperienze non fossero romantiche e sentimentali.

Comment: In questo brano, però, è l'"esperienza" quella che è "raspante e grifagna" e non l'aspetto fisico di Biagi.

Comment: Forse non ho spiegato con chiarezza che è all'esperienza che facevo riferimento. Un'esperienza ruspante e grifagna, a mio parere, significa qui che le esperienze di Biagi non erano romantiche e sentimentali.

Comment: @Charo Credo che Benedetta intenda che l'uso dei termini *ruspante* e *grifagna* è figurato. Parafrasando potremmo dire che l'esperienza era *terra terra* e *concreta*, e non *eterea* o *teorica*.